# mewebstudio/captcha wrong captcha in validation

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I know this topic is existing, but no one could solve my problem.
I am using the library `mewebstudio/captcha`, everything is fine, but when I submit, it tells me always that the captcha is wrong.

My validation rules:

```
'captcha' => 'required|captcha'
```

In my html form:

```
<?= captcha_img(); ?>
<input type="text" name="captcha">
```

I am using php5.6, Laravel 5.1 and mews/captcha 2.2

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a solution, I hope that will help someone in the future.
Well it is a bug in the library itself, where they delete the session key without checking the result:

```
public function check($value)
{
    if ( ! $this->session->has('captcha'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $key = $this->session->get('captcha.key');
    $sensitive = $this->session->get('captcha.sensitive');

    if ( ! $sensitive)
    {
        $value = $this->str->lower($value);
    }

    $this->session->remove('captcha');

    return $this->hasher->check($value, $key);
}
```

So my solution is like that (you need to extend the class, override the method and bind the class to the new implementation):

```
public function check($value)
{
    if ( ! $this->session->has('captcha'))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $key = $this->session->get('captcha.key');
    $sensitive = $this->session->get('captcha.sensitive');

    if ( ! $sensitive)
    {
        $value = $this->str->lower($value);
    }

    $isNotARobot = $this->hasher->check($value, $key);dd($isNotARobot);

    if ($isNotARobot) {
        $this->session->remove('captcha');
    }
    return $isNotARobot;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

```
'captcha' => ['required' , new CheckCaptcha]
```

Rule class :

```
public function passes($attribute, $value)
{
    return Hash::check($value, session('captcha.key'));
}

/**
 * Get the validation error message.
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function message()
{
    return 'Invalid captcha';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in CaptchaServiceProvider.php in package vendor, comment routes:

```
if ((double)$this->app->version() >= 5.2) {
            $router->get('captcha/api/{config?}', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptchaApi')->middleware('web');
            $router->get('captcha/{config?}', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptcha')->middleware('web');
        } else {
            $router->get('captcha/api/{config?}', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptchaApi');
            $router->get('captcha/{config?}', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptcha');
        }
```

then add routes above in your routes file witout middleware('web'):

```
Route::get('captcha/api/{config?}', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptchaApi');
Route::get('captcha/{config?}', '\Mews\Captcha\CaptchaController@getCaptcha');
```